# I want to install the OS (Windows) to a new SSD using "Recovery" -> "Reset this PC"

Tags: windows, windows-8, hard-drive, ssd

For doing that I understand that it detects the drive labeled "OS" to install Windows in that drive, so, if I rename the SSD to "OS" and the HDD partition to any other name, will the Recovery install to the SSD or do I need to do anything else?

Thank you for your advice.

Comment: You're trying to keep your data or go brand new installation ?

Comment: You cannot "install" Windows using that feature only repair an existing installation.  Just use the installation disk to install Windows instead of trying to do something like what you want to do.

Comment: Brand new installation.

Comment: Nope, I don't have an installation disk, is the partition that comes with a new laptop, when we use the "Recovery" option it activates that partition to install a fresh new OS in the indicated partition, for that is that I'm asking if it's possible by only relabeling

Comment: Make and model of PC?

Comment: Asus S56C, at present with Windows 10, but originally came with Windows 8.

Comment: So download the installation disk.  Media Creation Tool for Windows 10 does not require a license key to create it.  Windows 10 will automatically activate on your device since its been installed and activated once already

Comment: And how am I supposed to download the installation disk? I won't pay for it if I already have one.  I prefer to get an answer for the original question I asked, thank you @Ramhound for your time and effort, but that's not the answer I'm looking for.

Comment: It is 100% free.  You download the tool and you create a installation disk.  It literally takes the amount of time to download the .ISO plus the time it takes to place the data on the media of your choice.  Your desired solution, as written in the question, is not possible.  So time to change up your expectations.

Comment: Thank you, but that doesn't resolve my question, I specifically want to know if someone has done the relabeling stuff to have the Recovery option open, it's easier if in a place we have 100 PC's and laptops.